# problem with my css which is working on mozilla firefox but not on Chrome and safari?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, css

I create a small page with CSS, when i tested this on Mozilla firefox it works fine.  But when i tested the same on chrome, safari.  Its not working.  and when i created the CSS for chrome, its working on Safari but not on mozilla firefox.  Is there any solution to that.

Thanks in advance,  aby

```
span.back{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-55px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

span.header{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:30px;       
    margin-top:-12px;
    color:  #98AFC7;
       font-family: arial, verdana, ms sans serif;
            font-size: 14pt; 
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to give us some code, either a link, a copy and paste to here or a jsfiddle.

Comment: each browser has ways it handles particular CSS elements. Please post your code, which should give us an idea why stuff isn't working for you.

Comment: its complex.. there are too many things inside.. that why i thought to ask the question

Comment: @rick Bradshaw & @trickwallet: i have posted the code.

Comment: HTML:
<td class="topbar" height="50" bgcolor="green">
                    <div class="image">
                    <img src="back_button.png" align="left" width="80" height="30" alt="Back"/>
                        <span class="back" align="left">Back</span>            
</div></td><td bgcolor="green">          <span class="header" align="center">Product </span>  
          
    </td>        </tr>

Comment: @sandeep : how can i reset sheet?

Comment: copy the css from this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ & use it

Comment: Why are you using margins with position absolute? Use top and left. And as a general hint - don't use negative-margins. If you need a negative margin then you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe, for that positioning work,(although inside tables, might bring issues in several browsers)  you need to asign display:block property to .header and .back, as span is inline.

The html there is missing the opening tr, but I guess is just a copy/paste issue.
In general, is better to avoid so much deprecated html atributes and move them to a css sheet file. Those margins also might act differently in the several IE browsers.